# SQL - Is COUNT() possible in this situation?

Tags: sql, derby

I am working on a project that requires me to build a forum system from sketch

However I am facing a problem regarding SQL

I am using Derby Database.

Table Structure as follow.

```
 

TABLE ForumThread (
    TID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 , INCREMENT BY 1) Primary Key,
    TTitle varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    UID Integer NOT NULL,
    CID Char(7) NOT NULL,
    Sticky Boolean Not null,
    Status char(1)
)

==========Content and reply of a thread========
TABLE ForumThreadContent (
    RID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 , INCREMENT BY 1) Primary Key,
    Rcontent varchar(10000) Not Null,
    RTime Timestamp Not Null,
    REditTime Timestamp,
    UID Integer NOT NULL,
    TID Integer NOT NULL,
    Status Char(1) 
)


TABLE Users (
   UID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 , INCREMENT BY 1) Primary Key,
   UName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   UNick varchar(50) Not Null,
   ULoginName varchar(16) NOT NULL,
   Upwd varchar(16) NOT NULL,
   UPic varchar(200),
   UType Char(1) NOT NULL

)

=========Foreign Key==========
ALTER TABLE ForumThreadContent
ADD CONSTRAINT Forum_reply_fk_thread Foreign KEY (TID) REFERENCES ForumThread(TID);
Alter Table ForumThread
Add Constraint forum_thread_fk_User Foreign Key (UID) References Users(UID);
```

The UI Design of displaying a single thread in forum will be displayed the following information. With 10 threads to be displayed each page

- Thread Title (ForumThread.TTitle)
- Thread Author (Users.UNick)
- Number of replies in that thread
- Latest reply time (ForumThreadContent RTime)
- Latest replier's nickname (Users.UNick)

My SQL Statement.

```
SELECT ftc.tid ,ft.TTitle, ss.uNick as "Author", s.Unick as "Last replied by" , MAX(ftc.RTIME) as "Last Reply Time", COUNT(*) AS "Posts Count"
FROm ForumThreadContent ftc, Users s, ForumThread ft, Users ss
WHERE ftc.UID = s.UID
      AND ftc.TID = ft.TID 
      AND ft.UID = ss.UID
Group by ftc.tid , ft.ttitle , s.uNick , ss.uNick
Having MAX(ftc.RTIME) IN (SELECT MAX(ftcc1.RTime) 
                      FROM ForumThreadContent ftcc1 
                      WHERE ftc.TID = ftcc1.tid)
```

This statement can be executed without error.
Assuming there are **3 replies in TID "1"** , when I run it, the COUNT(*) only counted "2" for tid: 1.
To be clear:

- 3 rows in ForumThreadContent have a foreign key "1" of TID
- first rows of 3 rows has a foreign key "1" of UID
- The rest has a foreign key "2" of UID

Is it possible to do a count() function correctly in this situation? I can never get a number higher than 2 with my SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you. Please check for column names once

```
SELECT t1.tid, t1.Title, t1.Author, s1.Unick as 'Last replied by', ftc1.Rtime as 'last reply time', t1.count
FROM
(SELECT ftc.tid, ft.Title, s.UID, s.Unick as 'Author', COUNT(*) as count FROM 
ForumThreadContent ftc, Users s, ForumThread ft
where ftc.TID = ft.TID
and ft.UID = s.UID
group by ftc.tid, ft.title, s.UID) t1, Users s1, ForumThreadContent ftc1
where ftc1.rtime = (select max(rtime) from ForumThreadContent ftc2 where ftc2.tid = t1.tid)
and ftc1.uid = s2.uid
```